# When does a singular foliation admit a resolution?

Tags: singularity, singularity-theory, foliations

For example, Any holomorphic singular foliations on a complex manifold X of dimension n locally admits a finite resolution by finitely generated free OX-modules.

On the other hand, there are more general singular foliation which do not admit a resolution, not even an infinite resolution.

Are there known criteria for when and when not?
Is there a known obstruction?

Comment: A paper with some results in this direction for the finitely generated case is: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.00475